# Form is not submitted to Firebase database after some interval of time in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form which i need to submit to firebase database after 6 seconds automatically but when time reaches alert appears but form's data are not submitted .But when i click on button manually data are inserted in database

formHtml.php:

```
   <script src="application.js"></script>
    <div class="container">
    <form role="form" id="recommendationForm">

     <div class="form-group float-label-control">
      <input type="text" name="id" id="id" value="1" class="form-control" 
     placeholder="User Id" disabled>
                </div> 

         <div class="form-group float-label-control">
          <input type="text" name="" class="form-control" id="Fieldlatitude" 
           placeholder="Latitude" disabled>
                </div>

           <div class="form-group float-label-control"> 
                    <!-- <label for="">Password</label> -->
            <input type="text"  name="" class="form-control" id="FieldLongitude"  placeholder="Longitude" disabled>
                </div>

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
               </form>
           </div>
```

Application.js:

```
             firebase.initializeApp(config);

      // Reference to the recommendations object in your Firebase database
           var coordinates = firebase.database().ref("coordinates");

          // Save a new recommendation to the database, using the input in the form
       var submitCoordinates = function () {

     // Get input values from each of the form elements
     var id = $("#id").val();
     var latitude = $("#Fieldlatitude").val();
      var longitude = $("#FieldLongitude").val();

    // Push a new recommendation to the database using those values
     coordinates.push({
      "id": id,
    "latitude": latitude,
     "longitude": longitude
       });
       };
      function myFunction() {
       $("#recommendationForm").submit(submitCoordinates);
         };

      window.setInterval(function(){
   /// call your function here
   myFunction();
   alert("form data submited");
       }, 6000);  // Save data after 6 seconds
```

Comment: Why would you want to do something like that repeatedly in a setInterval? The only things that are going to change are three input values, for which a perfectly good `change` event fires on each change of value. Respond to that event instead of a regular poll and you will have have much more efficient code.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 , I don't  catch you well please show me how with my code above .thanks

Comment: @Roamer-1888, thank you for idea , i removed `myFunction()` and i replaced `var submitCoordinates = function () {`  by  `  window.setInterval(function(){` and it worked as i wish

Answer (score 0):

i removed myFunction() and i replaced var submitCoordinates = function () { by `window.setInterval(function(){` and it worked as i wish

```
   // Reference to the recommendations object in your Firebase database
            var coordinates = firebase.database().ref("coordinates");
          window.setInterval(function(){
      // Save a new recommendation to the database, using the input in the form
       // var submitCoordinates = function () {

   // Get input values from each of the form elements
  var id = $("#id").val();
  var latitude = $("#Fieldlatitude").val();
   var longitude = $("#FieldLongitude").val();

 Push a new recommendation to the database using those values
 coordinates.push({
"id": id,
 "latitude": latitude,
"longitude": longitude
  });

  $("#recommendationForm").submit();

    }, 0, 6000);
```

Comment: `$("#recommendationForm").submit()` is a little odd inside a setInterval. If a form is submitted, then the page is replaced and its javascript dies. Therefore your `setInterval(...)` will only fire once then die with the page! If you want a 6 second delay, before executing `coordinates.push()` and submitting the form, then use `setTimeout()` not `setInterval()`.